# How does a forward declaration work?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, recursion, forward-declaration

I understand declaring factorial before main. But how can main calculate the answer when the factorial formula comes after it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long factorial(int);

int main()
{
    int n;
    long long f;

    printf("Enter a number and I will return you its factorial:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);

    if (n < 0)
        printf("No negative numbers allowed!\n"); //prevent negative numbers
    else
    {
        f = factorial(n);
        printf("The factorial of %d is %ld\n", n, f);
    }

    return 0;
}

long long factorial(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return (n * factorial(n - 1));
}
```

Comment: You declared it before. That was all `main` needed to compile with hopes and dreams somewhere before the final-link finishes it will find a matching `factorial` to actually call.

Answer (score 4):

> But how can main calculate the answer when the factorial formula comes after it?

First thing — `main` does not calculate the answer; it's your `factorial` function which does it for you. Also there are 3 steps which I feel you need to know about when writing programs:

1. You write the code in a file.
2. You compile the file and the compiler checks for syntactical mistakes, no code calculation is happening in this phase its just mere lexical analysis.
3. Then linking takes place later. If you receive a linker error, it means that your code compiles fine, but that some function or library that is needed cannot be found. This occurs in what we call the linking stage and will prevent an executable from being generated. Many compilers do both the compiling and this linking stage.

Then when you *actually* run your code — it's then when the code's control flow goes into the `factorial` function when the calculation happens, i.e. at runtime. Use a [Debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to see this.

The below image is taken from [Compiling, Linking and Building C/C++ Applications](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html)

[image]

From [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration):

> In computer programming, a forward declaration is a declaration of an
>   identifier (denoting an entity such as a type, a variable, a constant,
>   or a function) for which the **programmer has not yet given a complete
>   definition**....
>   This is particularly useful for one-pass compilers and separate
>   compilation. Forward declaration is used in languages that require
>   declaration before use; it is necessary for mutual recursion in such
>   languages, as it is impossible to define such functions (or data
>   structures) without a forward reference in one definition: one of the
>   functions (respectively, data structures) must be defined first. It is
>   also useful to allow flexible code organization, for example if one
>   wishes to place the main body at the top, and called functions below
>   it.

So basically the `main` function does not **at all** need to know how `factorial` works.

Comment: Pretty picture. It is crazy that you made that so fast!

Comment: @self - Googled it ;).

Comment: If you get a diagram from somewhere else, you should give credit to that source in your answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks included the link.

Answer (score 1):

It works in this manner: let's take an example to find factorial of 3

Recursion :

[image]

As factorial of `0` is 1 and factorial of `1` is also 1, so you can write like

```
if(n <= 1)
     return 1;
```

Comment: I don't think that was the question. He was confused as why you can define a function after you use it (call it)

Comment: @bolov, you can see the question is edited, earlier it was "How is this recursion working?"

Answer (score 1):

> *But how can main calculate the answer when the factorial formula comes after it?*

The order in which a C program executes is only partially determined by the order in which the text appears.

For instance, look at the `printf` function you are using. That doesn't appear in your program at all; it is in a library which is linked to your program.

The forward declaration makes it known (from that point in the *translation unit*) that there is expected to exist such and such a function having a certain name, arguments and return value.

The simple answer is that *your C program is processed from beginning to end before it begins to execute*. So by the time `main` is called, the `factorial` function has already been seen and processed by the C compiler.

An address is assigned to the compiled `factorial` function, and that address is "backpatched" into the compiled `main` function when the program is linked.

The reason forward declarations are needed at all is that C is an old-fashioned language originally designed to allow *one-pass compilation*. This means that the compiler "translates as it goes": functions earlier in a *translation unit* are compiled and emitted before later functions are seen. To correctly compile a call to a function which appears later (or, generally, appears elsewhere, like in another translation unit), some information must be announced about that function so that it is known at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Since in main function when compiler sees this `f = factorial(n);` function, the compiler has no idea of what it means. it doesn't know where the function being defined, but it does know the argument the function is receiving is correct, because it's a user defined function that has its `definition` after main function.

Hence there should be some way to tell the compiler that I am using a function with name `factorial` which returns `long long` with a single `int` argument; therefore you define a `prototype` of the function before `main()`.

Whenever you call the function `factorial` the compiler cross checks with the function `prototype` and ensures correct function call.

A function prototype is not required if you define the function before main.

Example case where function prototyping is not required :

```
/*function prototyping is not required*/
long long factorial(int n)
{
 //body of factorial
}

int main()
{
 ...
 f=factorial(n);
 ... 
}
```

Here, the compiler knows the definition of `factorial`; it knows the return type, the argument type, and the function name as well, before it is called in main.